# Specialize template class for some types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization

How to make a template specialization for trivial types using is_trivial? At the same time, pointers are also trivial, but a separate specialization should remain for them.
i am using c++11.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#define Work(var)     A<decltype(var)>().print(&var);

//Base class
class ABase{
    public:
    virtual void print(void* ptr)=0;
};
//default template
template <class T> 
class A : public ABase{
    public:
    void print(void* ptr) override {
        std::cout<<"default "<<ptr<<" size:"<<sizeof(T)<<std::endl;
    }
};
// template for pointers
template <class T> 
class A<T*> : public ABase{
    public:
    void print(void* ptr) override {
        std::cout<<"pointer "<<ptr<<" content:"<<std::endl;
        T* val=static_cast<T*>(ptr);
        Work(*val);
    }
};
// template for arrays
template <class T, std::size_t N> 
class A<T[N]> : public ABase{
    public:
    void print(void* ptr) override {
        std::cout<<"array "<<ptr<<" size:"<<sizeof(T[N])<<" count:"<<N<<std::endl;
    }
};
// template for is_trivial    HOW?
template <> 
class A<int>: public ABase{  // MUST BE FOR ALL TYPES using std::is_trivial<T>::value
    typedef int T;
    public:
    void print(void* ptr) override {
        char* d= static_cast<char*>(ptr);
        std::cout<<"trivial "<<ptr<<" size:"<<sizeof(T)<<" dump:";
        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(T); i++)
            std::cout<<std::hex<<d[i];
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    int x=10;
    Work(x);
    char c[5]="qwe";
    Work(c);
    char* str= &c[1];
    Work(str);   
}
```

I saw how this is done for functions, but there was a template data type in the function header and it simplified everything

Comment: Please explain why newcomers cut out #include from their posted code? Don't they understand that they make the question harder to replicate? See the [mcve].

Comment: *HOW?* `std::is_fundamental`

Comment: The [CppReference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) for `std::is_trivial` says this: _The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `std::is_trivial` or `std::is_trivial_v` is undefined._

Comment: Ok, may be std::is_fundamental is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want C++11 specific solution, you can use `std::is_fundamental`, `std::enable_if` as shown below. Note that a second type parameter with a default has been added into the primary template for this to work:

```
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------->added second parameter with default
template <class T, typename = void> 
class A : public ABase{
    public:
    void print(void* ptr) override {
        std::cout<<"default "<<ptr<<" size:"<<sizeof(T)<<std::endl;
    }
};
//specialization for fundamental types
template <typename C> 
class A<C, typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<C>::value>::type>: public ABase{  
    
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n85YEPKEe)

Comment: it is not working on c++11.  Can you fix in fo gcc9 c++11 [link](https://godbolt.org/z/Eh7aWW6j8)

Comment: @АлексейФамилия See the updated example which will [work](https://godbolt.org/z/n85YEPKEe) with C++11.

Comment: If fix specialisation: 'class A<C, std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<C>::value, bool>::type>: public ABase' ...    **error**: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Final code [link](https://godbolt.org/z/4YfhcPnWh)

Comment: @АлексейФамилия You forgot to add the keyword `typename` before `class A<C, std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<C>::value, bool>::type>`. After you add `typename` it will work. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nMW549faY)

Answer (score 0):

In C++20 you can use `requires` as following. (For earlier language versions, use `std::enable_if` as explained in the other ansert.)

```
template <typename T> 
class A {};

template <typename T> requires std::is_fundamental_v<T>
class A<T> {};
```

Comment: i can not use c++20

Comment: @АлексейФамилия Ah, didn't notice that. I'll leave the answer in case somebody else needs this. I also suggest adding a language version tag in those cases, in addition to stating it in the question.